# ESLint - missing return type on function react component - Typescript error explanation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I already saw some of the answers for a similar question when the name of the component is defined, but I would like to understand more the logic behind ESLint with components exported as defaults as in my case.

**({ children }: AppProviderProps) =>** - according to ESLint: "Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types". Could someone explain to me why as I always thought it's a standard way to write React components? And what would be the solution in that case?

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../@state/createStore';


export default ({ children }: AppProviderProps) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    **my code**
  </Provider>
);

interface AppProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}
```

PS I know I can disable the rule, but would like to know how to write so ESLint wouldnt scream at me.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the difference. Can't you write return type on this function, as you'd do on named one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule [typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md) is telling you that your function requires and **explicit** return type. From the source:

> Explicit types for function return values and arguments makes it clear to any calling code what is the module boundary's input and output.

So you need to add the appropriate return type, which in your example is whatever the type of `<Provider />` is:

Replace `TypeOfProviderHere` with the correct type.

```
export default ({ children }: AppProviderProps): TypeOfProviderHere => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    **my code**
  </Provider>
);
```